# iPad app crash when submit an answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, ipad

When I submitted my answer in [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) (I hadn't registered in this site before), the app crash out. When I opened it back, my answer had disappeared. However, I was registered to this site automatically. I use iPad 2, the app is up-to-dated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll be building this out momentarily.  The long and the short of it is that we were doing pseudo-abstract methods in Objective-C and when I refactored the question editor I accidentally deleted an important method from the answer editor and the app crashed.  100% my fault. Sorry about that.

Also, why on earth wasn't I saving the draft as soon as you hit the "Submit" button?  I'll be pushing out some code to fix that too.

Comment: glad to hear that. Another thing, what is the phase that the app currently in? Alpha or beta? Inside the app it says *beta*, but when updating the web says *alpha*.

Comment: The names are loosely and inconsistently applied.  In general I think we're referring to our app store apps as beta because there's still so much stuff we can do to improve them; the preproduction version of the app is called both alpha and beta seemingly at random.  The real answer to the question is just that we have an app in the store which we think is good enough for the store, and we have a testing channel with things that are not yet ready for the store.